# Read Access Violation while trying to serialize a QObject class using QSettings

Tags: qt, qt5, qmetaobject

Hi everyone i have a foo class which is inherited from QObject and i want to serialize using QSettings.
Code in foo.h

```
namespace GUI
{
class Foo : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(QString mem1 READ mem1 WRITE setMem1 NOTIFY mem1Changed)
Q_PROPERTY(QString mem2 READ mem2 WRITE setMem2 NOTIFY mem2Changed)
Q_PROPERTY(int mem3 READ mem3 WRITE setMem3 NOTIFY mem3Changed)
public:
explicit Foo(QObject *parent = 0);
virtual ~Foo();
....
friend QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream& in, Foo* v);
friend QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& out, const Foo* v);
private:

QString mem1;
QString mem2;
int mem3;

};
}
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(GUI::Foo*)
```

Code in Foo.cpp

```
 QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& out, const Foo* v) {
 out << v->mem1 << v->mem2<< v->mem3;
 return out;
 }

 QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream& in, Foo& v) {
 in >>v->mem1;
 in >>v->mem2;
 in >>v->mem3
 return in;
 }
```

Code in main.cpp

```
qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<GUI::Foo*>("GUI::Foo*");
GUI::Foo c1 ;
QSettings saver;
saver.setValue("test1",QVariant::fromValue(&c1));
QSettings loader;
QVariant value = loader.value("test1");
GUI::Foo* t = value.value<GUI::Foo*>();
```

Now this is compiling fine  but when i debug it, i get Exception Triggered read access violation

```
 QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream& in, Foo& v) {
 in >>v->mem1; <- here i am getting read access violation and v is showing to be null
 in >>v->mem2;
 in >>v->mem3
 return in;
 }
```

One thing important to note is that if i change my friend function to

```
QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream& in, Foo* v) {
QString var1;
QString var2;
int var3;
in >> var1;
in >> var2;
in >> var3;
return in;
}
```

i do get the correct values in var1,var2 and var3.

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong and how can i rectify it 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Usually it's not advised to define data stream operators for pointers. You should create a data structure for serialization and create QObject manually using deserialized structure. In your code it's expected that `v` is null because your data class is `Foo*`, and it's default-constructed before calling `operator>>`, and default value for a pointer is 0 in Qt.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stream Operator Overload with pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626017/stream-operator-overload-with-pointers)